# How to fix itunes could not connect to the iphone because an invalid response was received from the device?

Tags: iphone, itunes, jailbreak, iphone-4

I have jailbroken device using Absinthe, 2 days back I removed the jailbreak.
Now I am not able to connect my iPhone 4 to iTunes. It says "`iTunes could not connect to the iPhone because an invalid response was received from the device`".
I have tried it on another system and also changed the cable.
Problem is as it is. Anybody please help me? Now I am not able to sync it.. :(

Answer (score 5):

Try resetting your network settings

Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings

And try deleting the contents of your mac/pc lockdown folder. Here's the link, follow the steps on "Reset the Lockdown folder".

http://support.apple.com/kb/ts2529

This one worked for me.